# rubymine output - how to show the puts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am new to rubymine. I have learned something about java by elipse. I want to see what happen in the process of rails.

```
def index

    #must be active and logged in the last month
    @users = User
                        .where("`is_active?` = true AND `last_sign_in_at` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)")
                        .reject{|u| u.biography.nil?}
                        .sort_by{|u| u.biography.last}
puts "haha"

end
```

I want to see puts "haha" in console. how can I see it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a test for the above? if so you can type shift control r or type rspec in to terminal.  otherwise just type the above into IRB.  just type irb into terminal and press enter.  Then enter the text and call index by typing index and hitting enter.

Comment: Weird. Ok, so I typed `rspec` into the console and got back an undefined something or other message. However, it started working after that o.0

Answer (score 2):

When you edit the configuration for debugging, you can use the menu to set these check-boxes which are by default un-checked in RubyMine 2017.1.1:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the [logger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger):

```
# environment.rb
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
Rails.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
config.log_level = :debug

# your code
logger.debug "Hmmm... That went well."
```

Comment: I met a problem, uninitialized constant Log4r (NameError)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Should have been one of them. You would need to use `log4r` gem for the lower one.

Comment: Thank you, I give up log4r, just use Rails.logger.debug("eeee"), it works.